# How to print strings in .txt file that is under a variable

Tags: python

So I'm asking the user to input two different .txt files to compare the strings inside. This is the return I want to get when the strings within the files are not the same is

```
No
String1
string2
```

I have everything working but I can't print the two strings inside each .txt file.

This is my code

```
print ('Enter the fist file name: ', end = '')
fileOne = input()

print ('Enter the fist file name: ', end = '')
fileTwo = input()

f1=open(fileOne,"r")
f2=open(fileTwo,"r")

if f1==f2:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('No')
    print(fileOne + fileTwo)
```

Comment: I guess you want to replace the line `print(fileOne + fileTwo)` with `print(f1.read(), f2.read())`

Comment: How would I make is print Yes? I guess it's not comparing the strings inside.

Comment: Same applies for `if` statement, as `if f1.read() == f2.read()`

Comment: Make sure you accept the answer that works best for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read first after open to get the content.

```
print ('Enter the fist file name: ', end = '')
fileOne = input()

print ('Enter the fist file name: ', end = '')
fileTwo = input()

f1=open(fileOne,"r").readlines()
f2=open(fileTwo,"r").readlines()

if f1==f2:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('No')
    print(f1)
    print(f2)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the file objects and the strings you can read out of them. The file objects won't be equal even if they have the same contents. Not only are they different files, file objects don't compare equal even if they're pointing to the same file, only if they are the same object. If you want to read the whole file into memory, use `.read()`, like

```
f1 = open(fileOne).read()
```

Then f1 is a string, which you can compare equal by contents.

Best practice is to close files when you're done with them. Python can do this for you if you use the `with` statement:

```
with open(fileOne) as f1:
    f1 = f1.read()
```